# Изменение цвета label при клике на него

Tags: html, css, css3

Доброго времени суток. Имеется `checkbox` внутри `label`. У `label` обводка и цвет фона - белый. Сам `checkbox` вынесен влево на `-10000px`. При `hover` на `label` меняем цвет фона.

Вопрос в следующем - как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на `label` цвет фона изменился и стал не белым. Т.е. до нажатия белый, а при нажатии, например, синий.

Пример кода, который есть сейчас, представлен ниже

```css
label {
  display: inline-table;
  border: 2px solid #00BCD4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}

label:hover {
  background: #00BCD4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="12">12</label>
```

Вариант только один мне приходит на ум - js. Стоит также сказать, что отделять `label` от `checkbox` нежелательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать обертку внутри `label`

Например, так

```css
label {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

label span {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00BCD4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}

label:hover span {
  background: #00BCD4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {  
  color: #fff;
  background: #00BCD4;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test" value="12"><span>12</span></label>
```